# Create request with include (Sequelize)

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models `Project` and `Version`.
`Project` has PK - `projectId`.
`Version` has PK - `versionId` and column `projectId`.
I want to create a request with Sequelize like this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM projects 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT projectId, MAX(updatedTime) AS modifiedTime FROM versions
  GROUP BY projectId
) last_modified
USING(projectId)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT projectId, updatedTime, editor FROM versions) last_modified_user
ON last_modified_user.projectId = projects.projectId
AND last_modified_user.updatedTime = last_modified.modifiedTime
```

Shema:
[Models chema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBvx4.png)

I wrote the association and started to create the request:

```
Project.hasMany(Version, {
  foreignKey: 'projectId', 
  sourceKey: 'projectId', 
  as: 'relatedVersion'
})

const project = async () => {
  const results = await Project.findAll({
    attributes: ['projectId', .....other column from Project] 
    raw: true,
    include: [
      {
        attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('relatedVersion.updatedTime')),'modifiedTime']]
        required: false,
        model: Version,
        as: 'relatedVersion'
      }
    ]
    // should the second join be here?
    group: ['relatedVersion.versionId','project.projectId']
  })
```

and then I stuck.

---

**Why Sequelize need to group the `versionId` column? I never use it.**
**And How I can write a query with Sequelize like with SQL above?**

Comment: You can try subqueries using Sequelize.literal in Project's `attributes` to get `MAX(updatedTime)` and `last_modified_user`.

Comment: please share your schema for this two tables .

Comment: @VyasArpit the schema was attached